# How to pass a Secret in Vault to imagePullSecrets to access an image in private registry in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I created a Secret in Vault in Kubernetes instead of using K8s API. And would like to use the Secret in Vault to pull images from a private registry. I am unable to find a way to do so. The following is the example code, assuming I used all the labels for Vault access by the Deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-app-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app-exporter
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app-exporter
        image: index.docker.io/xxxxx/test-app-exporter:3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 5000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: [myregistrykey--Secret From Vault]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the external secret or write a custom **CRD** solution also which ideally should sync or copy the secret from the **vault** to the Kubernetes **secret**.

**Option: 1**

You have multiple options to use [External Secret](https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.1/)

**steps for external secret**

- helm repo add external-secrets
- helm install k8s-external-secrets external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets

**Example ref**

```
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
 name: imagepull-secret
 namespace: default
spec:
 kvVersion: 1
 backendType: vault
 vaultMountPoint: kubernetes
 vaultRole: user-role
 data:
 - name: IMAGE_PULL
 ...
```

**Option : 2**

i have used this CRD personally and easy way to integrate [Vault-CRD](https://vault.koudingspawn.de/)

[Installation guide](https://vault.koudingspawn.de/install-vault-crd) & [Dockercfg](https://vault.koudingspawn.de/supported-secret-types/secret-type-dockercfg)

- Create a secret in vault first
- Create vault-crd YAML file

**Example**

```
apiVersion: "koudingspawn.de/v1"
kind: Vault
metadata:
  name: image-secret
spec:
  path: "secret/docker-hub"
  type: "DOCKERCFG"
```

- Apply YAML file to the cluster

it will fetch the secret from vault and create new secret in Kubernetes and you can directly use that secret to Deployment

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/kubelet-credential-provider/kubelet-credential-provider/ so kubelet can run vault executable to get the image pull credentials and kubelet/container runtime can pull the image using the credentials

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can use an external secret with the External Secret Operator, more info [here](https://external-secrets.io/).

If you create a external secret, you can reference the kubernetes secret in imagePullSecrets, but the actual value will be stored in vault, and synced. I found this links very useful:

- this one about the creation of a external secret linked with Vault
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-access-vault-secrets-inside-of-kubernetes-using-external-secrets-operator-eso
- this one about the configuration of the secret as a dockerconfigjson secret type  https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.1/guides/common-k8s-secret-types/#dockerconfigjson-example